# Remove element and reindex

Tags: php, arrays

the logic is to get last element from the elemnt after particular interval when all the elemnts are been removed. suppose there are five users and every secound user is been eliminated , then i have to find the last remaining user.

```
$foo = array(
    '0'=>'1',
    '1'=>'2',
    '2'=>'3',
    '3'=>'4',
    '4'=>'5',
    '5'=>'6'
);
```

now remove element indexed at 2 and reindex the array in below format.

```
$foo = array(
    '0'=>'4',
    '1'=>'5',
    '2'=>'6',
    '3'=>'1',
    '4'=>'2',
);
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: We are not here to do your work for you. Please show that you have at least *tried something yourself* or put some **research effort** into this problem before posting here.

Comment: i have used loops , used unset , slice functions i am able to remove and to reindex...but it is not indexing from the element it is been removed, i need the suggetion where i can try to implement not a complete solution.

Comment: @user2810175 did you check my answer?

Comment: @BenM: i have used slice, next current, split, unset, and also tried the loops, but i am not able to reindex the array from the next position where the elemnt is been removed

Comment: The sorting method you have provided doesn't make any sense at all. It's not a simply reindex as you indicated. Please can you provide more detail about the sorting algo that you want...

Comment: the logic is to get last element from the elemnt after particular interval when all the elemnts are been removed. suppose there are five users and every secound user is been eliminated , then i have to find the last remaining user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original question is a bit unclear. I understand you want to remove index X, and place all items after index X as first items in the array.

```
$index2remove = 2;
$newArray1 = array_slice($foo, $index2remove+1); // Get items after the selected index
$newArray2 = array_slice($foo, 0, $index2remove); // get everything before the selected index

$newArray = array_merge($newArray1, $newArray2); // and combine them
```

Or shorter and a bit less memory consuming (but harder to read):

```
$index2remove = 2;
$newArray = array_merge(
                array_slice($foo, $index2remove+1),  // add last items first
                array_slice($foo, 0, $index2remove) // add first items last
             );
```

You do NOT need to unset value 2 in my code, you simple slice it out. We do that with the -1 in the 2nd splice function.

If you want, you can replace `$newArray = array_merge()` with `$foo = array_merge()`, but ONLY in the second, if you dont need to save the original array.

*Edit: Changed small error, thank you [plain jane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2605821/plain-jane)*

Comment: you need to delete the array element at index 2

Comment: I changed the offset (`-1`) to +1 after the frist one :) The unset is not needed because of the +1. But you where right, thanks

Comment: i understand your logic of slicing the array before the required index and after index and merge...but at my end its giving wrong output

Comment: No problem, you helped me fix an index problem. Added your name to the topic

Comment: yeah, i too upvoted your answer as you didnt use `unset()` as in my case Cheers!!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php), but you'll also need to call [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to force a re-index. For example:

```
unset($foo[2]);
$foo = array_values($foo);
```

Comment: it is reindexing from the starting position not from next the element which is been removed

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. It makes no sense. If you remove the value at the second position from the array and reindex, you will have `0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 4, 3 => 5, 5 => 6`, not what you have posted above.

Comment: but programme logic need what i have posted...cant help myself in that case.. :(

Comment: But that's the point; I don't understand the logic. It has no sense.

Comment: the logic is to get last element from the elemnt after particular interval when all the elemnts are been removed. suppose there are five users and every secound user is been eliminated , then i have to find the last remaining user.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean and created an answer for you below

Answer (score 1):

Try this of which the output is given below

```
    $foo = array('0'=>'1','1'=>'2','2'=>'3','3'=>'4','4'=>'5','5'=>'6');
    //need to input this as the index of the element to be removed
    $remove_index = "2";
    unset($foo[$remove_index]);
    $slice1 = array_slice($foo, 0, $remove_index);
    $slice2 = array_slice($foo, $remove_index);
    $final_output = array_merge($slice2, $slice1);
```

Output

```
  Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
 )
```

Comment: The unsetting it not really needed, you could play arround with the `$remove_index+1`. This saves one action in the script, and leaves the original array intact in case its needed later-on. Still +1, it does exactly what the TO asked :)